# Create Web app pool and Site on on Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5, WiX 3.7

Tags: iis-7, wix, application-pool, wix3.7

Site is not getting created as intended. Please see the Image. Two virtual directories for CoreWebServicesV3 are getting created one pointing to default app-pool and another app-pool which I have created.

[image]

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="CoreWebservicesV3" >
          <Directory Id="WEBSITE" Name="$(var.CWSProductVersion)"/>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>



      <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="CoreWebservicesMSI" Level="1"  Display="expand" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION">

        <Component Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">
          <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Websites\CoreWebservices\3.0" Name="Remembered" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]" Type="string" />
          <RemoveFolder Id="CleanApplicationFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        </Component>


        <Feature Id="MainContent" Title="CoreWebservices Website"  Description="The CWS website content" Level="1">

          <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyWebIssConfiguration" />

          <ComponentGroupRef Id="CoreWebservices" />
        </Feature>

      </Feature>

<ComponentGroup Id="MyWebIssConfiguration">
      <ComponentRef Id="MyWebAppPoolCmp"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="MyWebsiteCmp"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="MyWebVirtualDirCmp"/>
</ComponentGroup>

<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION">

      <Component Id="MyWebsiteCmp" Guid="{751DEB01-ECC1-48ff-969A-65BCEE9E0528}" KeyPath="yes">
      <iis:WebSite Id="CoreWebservicesV3" Description='CoreWebservicesV3' Directory='INSTALLLOCATION' >
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
      </iis:WebSite>  
      </Component>


<Component Id="MyWebAppPoolCmp" Guid="{751DEB01-ECC1-48ff-869A-65BCEE9E0529}" KeyPath="yes">
         <util:User Id="MyWebAppPoolUser" 
                    CreateUser="no" 
                    Name="[IDENTITY_NAME]" 
                    Password="[IDENTITY_PWD]"  RemoveOnUninstall="yes" 
                    Domain="[IDENTITY_DOMAIN]" />
         <iis:WebAppPool Id="CWSWebAppPool" 
                    Name="[WEB_APP_NAME]" 
                    ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" 
                    ManagedPipelineMode="Integrated" 
                    Identity="other" 
                    User="MyWebAppPoolUser" >
         <iis:RecycleTime Value="00:00"/>
         </iis:WebAppPool>
</Component>


<Component Id="MyWebVirtualDirCmp" Guid="{751DEB01-ECC1-48ff-869A-65BCEE9E0528}" KeyPath="yes" >

<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="MyWebVirtualDir" Alias="[VIRTUAL_DIR_VAL]" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" WebSite="CoreWebservicesV3" >

<iis:WebDirProperties Id="MyWebVirtDirProperties" AnonymousAccess="no" BasicAuthentication="no" WindowsAuthentication="yes" />

<iis:WebApplication Id="MyWebWebApplication" Name="[VIRTUAL_DIR_VAL]" WebAppPool="CWSWebAppPool" />

</iis:WebVirtualDir>
</Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to narrow the problem down?

Comment: I made some changes ,now it is showing fine. But not sure it works or not until I test it. Here is what i did; commented out "MyWebVirtualDirCmp" component and have taken <iis:WebDirProperties> and <iis:WebApplication> tags out of <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION">. Then it shows fine.